# database data structure using powers of two

Tags: sql, binary, bit

I'm designing a data structure and wanted to know if I am missing anything doing it this way.

Lets say I have a column DAY of type int.

```
1  : Monday
2  : Tuesday
4  : Wednesday
8  : Thursday
16 : Friday
32 : Saturday
64 : Sunday
```

If I wanted to store Monday and Friday i would input 17 into the DAY column. If I wanted to store Tuesday and Wednesday I would enter 6 etc.

Is this a valid way of storing data. How would a query look if I wanted to select where a record contained Saturday and any variation of days, or Saturday but not Wednesday. Is this possible? Will it be fast?

What is this concept called?

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server?

Comment: Is there another type of RDBMS?  :)

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: <strike>you need to get a sense of humour. Even without the smiley face, it's obvious I'm joking. </strike> @Richard aka cyberkiwi removed his pointed remark about I should reread what the [sql] tags mean.

Comment: I tire of your personal attacks...". I do realize you commented in jest," - then why did you delete your original comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people may tell you that this is a code 'smell' because it represents denormalisation, but I think this is a perfectly valid use of a bit-mask field:

```
-- Contains Saturday and any other combination of days
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (DayBitColumn & 32) = 32

-- Contains Saturday and any other combination of days, except Wednesday
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (DayBitColumn & 32) = 32 AND (DayBitColumn & 4) = 0
```

EDIT: as pointed out by @Andriy M, this can be written more succinctly as:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (DayBitColumn & 36) = 32
```

['&' is bitwise AND]

Comment: `(DayBitColumn & 36) = 32`? (for the second example)

Comment: @Andriy: well spotted, updating.

Comment: Ironic this is marked "answer" when the comment against another answer is `I have decided not to use this [bitmask] method.`

Comment: Richard: None of the answers covered all my questions but this one directly answered the first question I asked. It's reasonable to select this as the accepted answer. Whether I use the method or not has no bearing on if an answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 2):

The crux of the question to me is

> Is this possible?
> Will it be fast?

Yes it is possible.
Yes and no - it depends on your data distribution.

If you stored them in bit fields, SQL Server will still internally store them into a single byte, which means you get all the goodness of storage, plus not having to **manually** do the bit masking.  ***Why duplicate the effort?***

Whether you store them separately or as a single field, indexing won't help.

- as individual fields: bit masks have terrible selectivity since there are only two keys
- as a single field: You cannot index a bit in a field, even if you can, it leads to the above point

If you however normalize it and store it in a secondary table, say Event_Day something like

```
EventID | Day
1         2
1         4
```

Storing only the days that an event occurs on, then you have just built a materialized index.  Of course you have to balance the benefit of that against having to PIVOT the data all the time to produce a nice weekly schedule.

Comment: "plus not having to manually do the bit masking" - Simple bit-masking is not particulary difficult.

Comment: @Mitch - Difficulty doesn't come into it. Storing two char(4) columns in one char(8) isn't `difficult` either. Bit packing is built in, use it.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi (or whatever your current name is): If you had a variable and/or unknown set of values perhaps use char(n), but more likely fully normalise; if you have a small number, guaranteed less than 32 values, use an int.

Comment: @Mitch - That comment is tangential to discussion. All I'm pointing out is that you can mash 7-bits into 1 byte or store 2 x char(4) attributes into 1 x char(8) column, but you wouldn't do the latter - unless you always retrieve the two attributes packed together. The question deals with finding things about specific days instead of retrieving the schedule (packed byte) per se, so splitting them out seems more appropriate.

Comment: I think you'll find it's 8 bits in a byte, not 7 as you state above.

Comment: @Mitch - while we are discussing **`this question`**, it is 7 bits being stored into a byte, or was that a joke?

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: yes we are. But that's not entirely clear from your wording.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is it possible? Yes. I make use of this on my current project database which involves reconciling checks. If an item should be excluded, I mark it in the skip column. Because there are many reasons to skip something, and I want to know why it was skipped, I set the flag with bitwise operators.

2) Is it fast? In limited cases. `WHERE skip = 0`? Fast. `WHERE skip & 4 = 4`... well, a table scan is in my future with all values being queried and operated on to fulfill my query.

Fast to insert, fast for selecting numeric ranges, but dog slow if you want to know everything that has a Monday flag set. Speedy if you want to know everything that has a Sunday flag set and know to query as `>= 64`.

[Mike Wheat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037028/database-data-structure-using-powers-of-two/5037096#5037096) has the proper queries for your other questions, so I won't duplicate that. Note again they'll need a table scan and will not be speedy. If you do have them as individual columns, AND you index against each of those columns, you'll consume a lot of space making indexes. You will see limited benefit from that in a table unless they are covering indexes... Saturday + anything but Wednesday would still have to scan either all of Saturday or all of Wednesday in a day-per-column config. Table scanning all of them in that scenario may end up being faster than seeking depending on data scattering and such.

Comment: Thanks for this answer on performance. I have decided not to use this method.